# Unable to download

Tags: android

I am making an android app (testing with a physical device running 4.4.4) and every once in a while when I fresh run it or open it if it's already installed then it shows a `"Currently unable to download. Please try again later"` toast. I'm not downloading anything within the app, I don't use internet, I'm not sure which files are relevant, someone let me know and I can post them. I have no idea where this could be coming from.

The only thing I can think of is possibly SharedPreference is doing something weird? I'll post my gradle at least.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.apps.andapp.appname"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
}
```